# SQL dependency C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr

I am looking to have live data on UI table, I want to get the data from a SQL Server stored procedure that uses a table valued function but I get an invalid subscription error when the dependency change is called.

```
SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(_connectionStringTest);

var messages = new List<WorkToListHeaderModel>();

SqlDependency.Stop(_connectionStringTest);
SqlDependency.Start(_connectionStringTest);

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"[DBO].[spTest]", co))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Notification = null;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        messages.Add(item: new WorkToListHeaderModel
                    {
                        SalesOrderNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    });
    }
}

return messages;

private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        MyHub.SendMessages();
    }
}
```

The SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]   
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT SalesOrderNumber, Test 
    FROM dbo.[TableTest]('z')
END
```

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TableTest]
    (@SalesOrderNumber NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS 
    @Table TABLE
           (
               SalesOrderNumber NVARCHAR(100),
               Test NVARCHAR(150)

           )
AS
BEGIN 
    ;WITH Selects AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            AdamTest.SalesOrderNumber,
            TEST AS CustomerName
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Test] 
        LEFT JOIN 
            DBO.Test2 ON Test2.SALESORDERNUMBER = Test.SalesOrderNumber
    )
    INSERT INTO @Table
        SELECT DISTINCT s.SalesOrderNumber, s.CustomerName
        FROM Selects AS S

    RETURN
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you change that multi-line table value function to an inline table value function; the latter are far more performant.

Comment: Pet Peeve: The Semi Colon (`;`) is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the end of *all* your statements, not the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: @Larnu which bit of code are you referring to for the ; ?

Comment: The one where you start your SQL Statement with a `;`.

Comment: @Larnu I have changed the table valued function but I still get an invalid subscription

Comment: `;WITH ...` is probably what Larnu's on about. It's a common pet peeve.

Comment: well but having a semicolon right after the block start `BEGIN`, which is per token type not a statement on its own, would look odd, too

Comment: You're disposing the command, plus you're reusing it for both the adapter and the dependency. Also that function is kinda weird, you're not actually using the parameter.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes the function is a bit weird I made it just to test the code. What do you mean by disposing the command?

Comment: You have a `using` on the SqlCommand, so it will be disposed. Meanwhile, the SqlDependency is relying on it. But that is how [the example code does it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency#example), so it's probably correct. You should dispose the `co` connection object though. I would imagine you want to cache the `dependency` object, otherwise it could get disposed.